# fails to link if a dependency has another dependency that needs to link with a static library

Tags: linker, static-libraries, d

I have a library ([qui](https://github.com/Nafees10/qui/releases/tag/v0.2.0)) that depends on the another library ([termbox-d](https://github.com/zyedidia/termbox-d)). And termbox-d links with a static library `libtermbox.a`.

Note: the termbox-d I linked to has some bugs which I've fixed in my [fork](https://github.com/Nafees10/termbox-d) but pull request has yet to be merged.

And this is where things gets messed up:
If I compile `qui` as a library, it will compile. Indicating that `termbox-d` linked with `libtermbox.a`.

If I compile `qui` with `dub build --comfig=demo`, it will build it as a executable with a main that uses `qui` library which uses `termbox-d`. This build and runs fine. Indicating that it still linked fine.

But if I create another package, that depends on `qui`, and build it, it fails to link with libtermbox.a. I get errors like:
`source/termbox/package.d:210: undefined reference to`tb_peek_event'
`So now it failed to link with`libtermbox.a`

Why does this happen, and how I make it work?

Comment: the problem might be because your package is a "sourceLibrary", which means it acts as if the code and all configuration is inside your project which uses it and not a separate library to compile & link. I suspect it is looking for the .a file in your local project because of that. Try changing it to "library" or "staticLibrary" to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: @WebFreak001 tried that. Didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to alphaglosined on IRC channel #d on chat.freenode.net, I figured out the issue:
Instead of adding
`"sourceFiles" : ["libtermbox.a"]`
to `qui`'s `dub.json`, I had to add
`"lflags" : ["$PACKAGE_DIR/libtermbox.a"]`.
And now it works.